# Function parameter where I can pass in Set<Int> or [Int]

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Basically I want to be able to pass in either `Set<Int>` or `[Int]` Or any thing where at the very least, I can iterate through an unordered set of `Int`.

I would rather not have to convert `[Int]` to a `Set<Int>` (and vice versa). And I would like to avoid making to functions that require something different (`[Int]` or `Set<Int>`) but do the same thing, which is what I'm doing now.

I use this function in many places and the callers sometimes care about order (`[Int]`) and sometimes not (`Set<Int>`). But the function does not require any specific order.

---

Something like this:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element: Int { }
```

but as a parameter.

---

**Function Example (as requested):**

The `Int` as explained above was just for simplification, my example is some data object.

```
struct TextNumber {
    let text: String
    let number: Int
}
```

And here is the essentials of what I want to do with the data.

```
func sendUpTextNumberArray(arrayOfTextNumber: [TextNumber]) {
    var convertedData = [[String:AnyObject]]()
    for textNumber in arrayOfTextNumber {
        convertedData.append(textNumber.convert())
    }
    Service.sendJSON(convertedData)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example for what this function would do with the function parameter itself?

Comment: I think you are going to have to pick one for the actual function (I would suggest `[Int]`) and then create a second function that wraps the first: `firstFunction(Array(input))`

Comment: @Dan, I just added an example. Leo Dabus gave an awesome answer that works for my needs, I'm open to anything else as well though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follow:

Swift 2

```
let setOfIntegers = Set([1,2,3])
let arrayOfIntegers = [1,2,3]

func sum<T: SequenceType where T.Generator.Element == Int>(integers: T) -> T.Generator.Element {
    return integers.reduce(0, combine: +)
}

sum(arrayOfIntegers)  // 6
sum(setOfIntegers)    // 6
```

---

Swift 3

```
func sum<T: Sequence where T.Iterator.Element == Int>(_ integers: T) -> T.Iterator.Element {
    return integers.reduce(0, combine: +)
}

sum(arrayOfIntegers)  // 6
sum(setOfIntegers)    // 6
```

Comment: Awesome! I thought it was possible, just couldn't think of the right way to do it. Thank you!